# Get the rgb of overlaying colors (elements)

Tags: javascript, math, colors, color-theory

Let's say I have the following setup

```
body {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#first {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
#second {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(86, 185, 11, .5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

How can I get/calculate the color of the `#second` div?

---

I took a screenshot of the divs and checked their RGBs in Photoshop.

```
Body                 -> 128,128,128
First red div        -> 192,65,65
Second yellowish div -> 140,125,38
```

[image]

I found a way to calculate the first div's rgb by experimenting. Adding the two values together and then applying the alpha.

```
R: (128 + 255) * 0.5 = 191.5
G: (128 + 0)   * 0.5 = 64
B: (128 + 0)   * 0.5 = 64
```

Tried to use the same method on the second div, but it gets trickier now.

```
R: (((128 + 255) * 0.5) + 86)  * 0.5 = 138.5
G: (((128 + 0)   * 0.5) + 185) * 0.5 = 124.5
B: (((128 + 0)   * 0.5) + 11)  * 0.5 = 37.5
```

I can round the G and B to get the exact result, but R is off by 1.5. And if I increase the number of the color layers, I don't know what kind of results I'll get.

Is there a better way to calculate it?

---

**Update** : As Kaiido suggested, I tried using canvas. Created the same thing using rectangles: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/bp5tLmx4/). Used `getImageData` to extract the rgb of the second rectabgle. The returned value was `[122, 105, 6, 223]`. Not used to using 8-bit integers for the alpha value, so it's `[122, 105, 6, 0.8754]`. Even though I've extracted some rgb value, it's not a solid color and it's definitely not what I measured in Photoshop which is `140,125,38`.

Also when I took a screenshot of the canvas and checked the second rectangle's color, it was `139, 124, 37`, but the color of the #second [div](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/zz3mvzqo/) is `140,125,38`. They are not exactly the same.

Anyway, I searched for a way to convert the returned value from the `getImageData` that is `122, 105, 6, 0.8754` to `140,125,38`. I thought if I compensate for the missing opacity with the following example, I'd get the desired value

```
122 * (255/223) = 139.5 // 140
105 * (255/223) = 120   // 125
6   * (255/223) = 6.86  // 38
```

which I did for R, but the same method doesn't work for G, and B. I came to think that canvas won't really help unless there's a way to convert the transparent color to a solid color.

Comment: I think I would go with canvas, drawing rectangles of the same colors, then grab the final value with `getImageData`. But, you will have to check where the elements overlay etc. Maybe you could also give html2canvas lib a try.

Comment: @Kaiido I tried your method and extracted some color value, but there are still some issues. See my update.

Comment: @akinurt, the easy way to convert transparent to solid color in canvas is to fillRect the entire canvas in white before :-)

Comment: @Kaiido Haha. I applied `background-color: white` instead. Drawing a white rectangle worked. Although there's one little problem. imageData returns `[139, 124, 37, 255]` for the second rectangle, but the final color of the #second div is `140,125,38`. Do you have any idea why are canvas and div colors not the same?

Comment: Certainly because the color profile is different. Also, if by final color you mean the one you got from PS, you've to know that you processed 3 times the color : 1st in CSS, second while snapshooting, third while opening it in PS. If I do use a system colorPicker directly on the CSS, then on the snapshot, and finally on the opened file in PS, I don't have a single time the same values as PS gives me. Also, I think doing what you want to do is quite unefficient, since I think that different devices, will perform blending with different algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Kaiido's approach, I managed to get the end result of the overlaying colors using canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// default background
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fill();

// body
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
context.fill();

// first div
context.beginPath();
context.rect(10, 10, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
context.fill();

// second div
context.beginPath();
context.rect(20, 20, 50, 50);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(86, 185, 11, .5)";
context.fill();

var imageData = context.getImageData(25, 25, 1, 1).data;

console.log(imageData); // 139,124,37
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Although this gives me what I want, I still would like to this mathematically.